# Getting ERROR mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on Angular form where I am trying to validate a reactive form .
For template I am using Material design in my project ,

I am getting error on putting condition ngIf for validation in the textbox

> error is -: ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a
>   MatFormFieldControl.

Please see -:

To remove this issue I have already 
 1. imported MatInputModule in module.ts file 
 2. Already added You have to add matInput to input

But still getting same error

I am putting code below

**template -:**

```
<form class="example-form" novalidate (ngSubmit)='user_signup(user)'  [formGroup]='user'>

          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <label><img src="assets/imgs/mobile-icon.svg"/></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
                <input matInput type='number' placeholder="Phone Number:"  maxlength="10" name="phone" formControlName="phone" *ngIf="( user.get('phone').hasError('required') || user.get('phone').hasError('minlength') || user.get('phone').hasError('maxlength'))&& user.get('phone').touched" required/>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div>
              <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('phone').hasError('required') && user.get('phone').touched">
                Phone number Required
              </div>
              <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('phone').hasError('minlength') && user.get('phone').touched">
                Min 10 digit
              </div>
              <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('phone').hasError('maxlength') && user.get('phone').touched">
                Max 10 digit
              </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ServicesService } from '../service/services.service';
    import { FormGroup  , FormControl  , Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
     user: FormGroup;
 constructor( public restapi:ServicesService) {

        this.user = new FormGroup({
          password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
          email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.email]),
          phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10)]),
          });

       }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ComponentsComponent } from './components/components.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule }    from '@angular/common/http';


import { MDBBootstrapModule, WavesModule, ButtonsModule, CardsFreeModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { MatTabsModule, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';


/*angular material compoment*/
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';

/*component */
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { FleshScreenComponent } from './flesh-screen/flesh-screen.component';


/* Service */
import { ServicesService } from './service/services.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ComponentsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    FleshScreenComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
    HttpClientModule ,
    MatFormFieldModule

  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [ServicesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have you tried moving the formConttrolName to the mat form field ?

Comment: Not yet how I can do that

Comment: Please consider not importing some modules from the main entrypoint and other modules from the secondary entrypoints. Consider importing all of the Material modules from either the main entrypoint, or import the modules from the dedicated entrypoints.

Comment: @Edric I could not understand can you please elaborate ..

Comment: For instance, you're importing `MatFormFieldModule` from `@angular/material`. Further down in the same code, you're importing `MatInputModule` from `@angular/material/input`, `MatButtonModule` from `@angular/material/button` and so on. What I'm advising you to do is to import all modules from the same root. (As in you should use the same import instead of importing a subpath entry point.) (For example, import `MatButtonModule` from `@angular/material` instead.)

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer `formControlName` is supposed to be meant to use on a `input` element.

Comment: @Edric sure thing but the <mat form field> is bitching that it has no formControl. Thats where my concerns lay

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it out, but you might be getting this error because of the `*ngIf` directive applied on the `input` element.

#### Why?

In particular, in this part of your code:

```html
<mat-form-field>

    <input *ngIf="...">

</mat-form-field>
```

Angular interprets it [as follows](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-shorthand):

```html
<mat-form-field>

    <ng-template [ngIf]="...">
      <input>
    </ng-template>

</mat-form-field>
```

So under the hood, the `input` element is not a direct content child of `mat-form-field`. No problem so far.

However, after digging a little bit into its [source](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-shorthand), `MatFormField` needs to find your `input` (with `matInput` directive applied) via `@ContentChild`. This means that you must supply your `input` element as a content child of `mat-form-field`.

In short, you need to place your `input` element directly under the `mat-form-field` element in some way.

#### Solution

Instead of applying `*ngIf` to the `input` element, apply it to `mat-form-field`, instead. That way, the `input` element is a content child of `mat-form-field`, as it should be.

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="...">
    <input>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a **mat-form-field** tag the inner **input/ select** tag, the tag must contain the **matNativeControl** attribute with it.

eg:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput matNativeControl placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Refer official docs: [Link](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there is a typo error please change your code to this

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
              <input matInput type='number' placeholder="Phone Number:"  maxlength="10" name="phone" formControlName="phone" *ngIf="user.get('phone').hasError('required') || user.get('phone').hasError('minlength') || user.get('phone').hasError('maxlength') && user.get('phone').touched" required/>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

MatFormControl refers to formControl that is or should be used with that form field. Using directives can lead to non rendering of the input element. Thus resluting in the require error.